# Forcing a draw in TicTacToe

Tags: game-theory

Let's consider the game of Tic-Tac-Toe on a $3\times3$ board. The first player places a cross in any free square. The second player places a circle in another free square. This continues. The first to have $3$ shapes in a row (also in the diagonals) has won.

> Show that the second player can always be sure not to lose.

I would like to find something else than a game tree.

Comment: I'm curious why a game tree isn't sufficient. It would be very small in this case. Do you just want an answer with more insight?

Comment: @TheCount Could you please show me the game tree? But yea, I am searching something more insight as you said...

Comment: Well, Shaun has solved things, now.

Comment: Duplcate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2156604/265466

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is flawed. It's possible that the game could end in a draw.

For instance,

$$\begin{align}
X O O \\
X X O \\
O X X
\end{align}$$

is a complete $3\times 3$ board that ends in a draw. (If diagonals are included and the first player is X, the first player could win here too.)

> The second player can force a draw.

Use a case by case analysis for the first player starting in the top right, the top middle, and the middle squares, then use the symmetry of a square to eliminate similar boards, like so:

$$\begin{align}
X_1 O_1 \phi \\
X_2 \phi \phi \\
O_2 \phi \phi
\end{align}$$

for the top right case,

$$\begin{align}
\phi X_1 O_1 \\
\phi X_2 \phi \\
\phi O_2 \phi
\end{align}$$

for the top middle case, and

$$\begin{align}
\phi X_2 \phi \\
\phi X_1 O_2 \\
\phi O_1 \phi
\end{align}$$

for the middle case.

(Here $\phi$ is an empty square and $\Delta_n$ is the $n$th move of the player with symbol $\Delta$, assuming $X$ comes first.)

In each case the second player will always seek to prevent the first player from getting three $X$s in a row, so, up to the symmetries of a square, the cases above suffice to show that the second player can force a draw.

Comment: Is a draw counted as a win?

Comment: I suppose drawing isn't losing.

Comment: Yea sorry that was what I meant, show that the second player can force a draw...

Comment: And what if the second move of the first player in your first case would be to place it in the center?

Comment: The first player wouldn't do that, @DanielCortild; or would but would soon be cut off for three in a row options. I'm not sure that's clear though.